# How to properly code the confirm dialogs with Android?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

It's supposed to be a very common thing: having dialog boxes to confirm to proceed the flow of the interaction with users. But the best I can come up with with the information I've dug doesn't seem good to me.  I primarily extended DialogFragment (following the first searches for examples) and implement the NoticeDialogListener.

I came to believe that this is not the better way because as far as program flow is concerned, it's very cumbersome.  Program flow-wise I understand it can be cumbersome anyway as Dialog appears as another thread from the main to begin with, but I suppose there should be a better way to assign different responding method to different dialog.  But I haven't been able to find a way except what's following.

Hopefully I've described my question clearly. Thanks in advance for the response.

```
public class Confirm extends DialogFragment {

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(sQ);
        builder
                .setPositiveButton(sYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        mListener.Yes();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(sNo, null);
        return builder.create();
    }

    public interface NoticeDialogListener {
        void Yes();
    }
    private NoticeDialogListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
    }
}

public class Main extends ActionBarActivity
        implements Confirm.NoticeDialogListener {
...

    private int iDialogMode;
    private final static int DIALOG_ST_0 = 0;
    private final static int DIALOG_ST_1 = DIALOG_ST_1 + 1;
    private final static int DIALOG_ST_2 = DIALOG_ST_1 + 1;

    @Override
    public void Yes() {
        switch (iDialogMode) {
            case DIALOG_ST_0: // follow up HERE0 for what that dialog prompted
                break;
            case DIALOG_ST_1: // HERE1: feeling not smart
                break;
            case DIALOG_ST_2: // HERE2: believe there should be a better way
                break;
        }
    }

    public ... State_0_doing_something (...) {
        ...
        Confirm diaBox = new Confirm (...);
        iDialogMode = DIALOG_ST_0;
        diaBox.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "State_0");
        // what's supposed to continue if confirmed will be followed up in HERE0 in Yes() 
    }

    public ... State_1_doing_something_else (...) {
        ...
        Confirm diaBox = new Confirm (...);
        iDialogMode = DIALOG_ST_1;
        diaBox.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "State_2");
        // what's supposed to continue if confirmed will be followed up in HERE1 in Yes() 
    }

    public ... State_2_doing_yet_something_else (...) {
        ...
        Confirm diaBox = new Confirm (...);
        iDialogMode = DIALOG_ST_2;
        diaBox.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "State_3");
        // what's supposed to continue if confirmed will be followed up in HERE2 in Yes() 
    }
}
```

I am thinking if I can attach a different click listener to each Confirm dialog box created instead of setting the dialog mode/state using *global* variable/member like that.  Am missing function pointers here...

Comment: By the way, how come I couldn't properly post the beginning declaration and ending bracket in the grey box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the only problem is that it's not as nice looking

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.theContext);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_delete);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm_yes, vCabDelete());
            builder.setNegativeButton(Home.theContext.getString(R.string.confirm_no), null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

....

private static DialogInterface.OnClickListener vCabDelete() {
    return new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int id) {
            ....
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"By the way, how come I couldn't properly post the beginning declaration and ending bracket in the grey box? "

Add 4 blank spaces before that text, or add the ` character at the beggining and end of the code text.
Example:
`Fake code that does nothing`

"Program flow-wise I understand it can be cumbersome anyway as Dialog appears as another thread from the main to begin with"

This is basically why its not intended for the user to keep on using dialog boxes. The way I saw most programs so far, is that only actions that could severely delay the application or that could possibly charge the user would use dialogs.

Also, note the Activity lifecycle will make you keep its "state" remembered, this can further add to issues with onPause/onResume with your app.

Comment: What's would be a recommended alternative for the purpose?